# OpenNebula fails to monitor host: Could not resolve hostname

Tags: debian, opennebula

hope can get some advise n help....
currently I am installing opennebula 3.4 in debian squeeze everything have being successful where I am able to access the opennebula sunstone webpage localhost:9869 , use one command 
but when I tried to create a host the status become error...
hope someone can assist me on this thanks
sample log

```
 Monitoring host abc (0)
 [InM][I]: Command execution fail: 'if [ -x "/var/tmp/one/im/run_probes" ]; then /var/tmp/one/im/run_probes kvm 0 abc; else                              exit 42; fi'
 [InM][I]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname abc: Name or service not known
 [InM][I]: ExitCode: 255
 [InM][E]: Error monitoring host 0 : MONITOR FAILURE 0 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refs: http://opennebula.org/documentation:rel3.4:hostsubsystem

> OpenNebula's Frontend and all the Hosts need to be able to resolve,
>   either by DNS or by /etc/hosts the names of all the other Hosts and
>   Frontend.

If you don't have a local DNS server, you should add in the **/etc/hosts** of every host a few lines mapping the IP address and the hostname of every host, e.g.:

```
192.168.1.10 opennebula
192.168.1.11 abc
192.168.1.12 cde
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your DNS configuration. OpenNebula cannot resolve the given hostname.

Maybe you should look into your DNS config and make sure that the names a resolvable.